# troubleshooting NoMethodError: undefined method `formats=' for #<Controller@_url_options=nil>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

I am attempting to implement Oauth and am creating a test for requesting tokens. The code below is my controller test for requesting a token. Where my tests break is at the point where the code reaches `post :request_token` from which I get the error above only its for the Authorizations controller.

Below is my test code:

```
   def test_request_token
      @options = default_oauth_parameters(api_keys(:first))
      @signature = OAuth::Signature::HMAC::SHA1.new(
        RequestMock.new('POST', @request.url + 'oauth/request_token', @options)
      ) do
        [nil, api_keys(:first).secret]
      end
      assert_difference 'Authorization.count' do
        binding.pry
        post :request_token, @options.merge(:oauth_signature => @signature.signature    )
        assert_response :success
      end
      @authorization = api_keys(:first).reload.authorizations.first
      assert @authorization
      assert_equal "oauth_token=#{@authorization.token}&oauth_token_secret=#{@author    ization.secret}", @response.body
    end
```

From my trouble shooting, I suspect that my error is in the config/routes.rb file. I believe that /oauth/test_request is not accepting either get or post requests which I confirmed using binding.pry. However, with the code below you can see that my oauth/request_token route is mapped to the authorizations controller via get and post. It should be able to accept the requests. What could be wrong?

Below is my routes.rb:

```
root 'home#index'

 resources :api_keys, only: :index
 resources :domain_blacklists, except: :show

 resources :accounts, except: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :delete] do
   resources :api_keys, constraints: { format: :html }, except: :show
   member do
    get :settings
  end
  resources :authorizations
end

get '/oauth/test_request',  :to => 'authorizations#test_request',  :as => :test_request
get '/oauth/access_token',  :to => 'authorizations#access_token',  :as => :access_token
match '/oauth/request_token', :to => 'authorizations#request_token', :as => :request_token, via: [:get, :post    ]

get '/oauth/authorize',     :to => 'authorizations#authorize',     :as => :authorize
get 'coverage' => 'coverage#index'
```

This problem is a customized solution that I am implementing and I'm only expecting leads from the community from where to try looking. To be even more specific my code breaks at this point of the main ruby packages

```
gems/actionpack-4.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal/testing.rb
```

at this point:

```
module Functional # :nodoc:
  def set_response!(request)
  end

  def recycle!
    @_url_options = nil
    self.formats = nil
    self.params = nil
  end
end
```

Does someone in the community have a good lead that I can try? Help would be appreciatd and I can provide more information if it is needed for troubleshooting. Thanks.